# Question about composition of morphisms of schemes (Mumford's)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

On section 7 of Chapter 2 of Mumford's Red Book, there is the following statement:

Suppose $X\stackrel{f}{\rightarrow}Y\stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}Z$ are morphisms of schemes, such that $g$ is of finite type, $f$ is surjective and $g\circ f$ is proper. Then $g$ is proper.

As I've said in my previous questions, I'm not quite familiar with algebraic geometry, and I can't figure out how to use the universally closure property together with the hypothesis about the surjectivity of $f$ to conclude that $g$ is proper. So, my question is, how to prove this.

Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a base extension $Z'\rightarrow Z$ we want to prove that $g_{(Z')}:Y\times_ZZ'\rightarrow Z'$ is closed. Since surjectivity is preserved under base extension then the map $f\times 1_{Z'}:X\times_Z Z'\rightarrow Y\times_ZZ'$ is surjective implying that any closed subset of $Y\times_ZZ'$ is of the form $f\times 1_{Z'}(E)$ for some closed subset $E$ of $X\times_ZZ'$. The map $(g\circ f)_{(Z')}:X\times_ZZ'\rightarrow Z'$ is closed by the hypothesis on $g\circ f$. Now it is easy to see that $g_{(Z')}\circ(f\times 1_{Z'})=(g\circ f)_{(Z')}$ and from this and the remarks above it follows that $g_{(Z')}$ is closed.

Comment: Is it hard to show that surjective morphisms are preserved under base extension? Restricting to the affine case, this is equivalent to asking that if $A \to B$ are $C$-algebras such that the morphism satisfies the lying over property and $D \to C$ is a morphism, then the extended morphism $A \otimes_C D \to B \otimes_C D$ still satisfies the lying-over property. This does not seem trivial. (I am interested in this for other reasons than this question, but you seem to know that it holds...)

Comment: To say  that a map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is suryective is equivalent to say that for any field $K$ and any morphism $Spec(K)\rightarrow Y$ there exist a field extension $K'$ of $K$ and a morphism $Spec(K')\rightarrow X$ such that $Spec(K')\rightarrow Y\rightarrow X=Spec(K')\rightarrow Spec(K)\rightarrow Y$.  With this it should be easy to prove that a base extension of surjective morphism is surjective

Comment: Actually what I wrote is wrong, it's not what it is equivalent to, it's what I need in my problem (which is a particular case)... but I was pretty tired so I didn't notice until later. I'll give it a thought with your comment, thanks.